# Setting a drop downlist to a specific value in MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, drop-down-menu

Afternoon all.

I have a drop down list in my **view**

```
    <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteTypeId, "SiteType")
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownList("SiteTypeId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.SiteTypeId)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteTypeId)
                </div>
```

With the **model** looking like so:

```
public class SiteType
        {
            [Key]
            public int SiteTypeId { get; set; }
            public string SiteTypeName { get; set; }
        }
```

Currently there are just the two items in the drop down:

```
1 (value) - Foo (item)  
2 (value) - Bar (item)
```

Which appears via the **controller** a la:

```
public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
    {
        var model = Model(id);

        ViewBag.SiteTypeId = new SelectList(db.SiteTypes, "SiteTypeId", "SiteTypeName");
        return View(model.Details);
    }
```

Users will update this accordingly and it will get stored in a database.

I can get the value of the drop down list from the database no problem, but how would I got about effectively binding this value to the list?

Man I feel simple asking this :'(

Any help always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the same name for the `ViewBag` parameter containing the SelectList as the first argument of the DropDownList helper:

```
ViewBag.SiteTypes = new SelectList(db.SiteTypes, "SiteTypeId", "SiteTypeName");
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SiteTypeId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SiteTypes)
```

Now inside the POST action when this form is submitted the selected value will be passed as a parameter called `SiteTypeId`.

Comment: Oh my word...time to go home me thinks Darin!